# L'hopital limit. Problem

Tags: calculus, limits

I trying to show

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x}{x+1} \right)^x $$

I know the answer using wolfram or a calculator,  but I stuck trying to figure out how to apply L'hopital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

First note that we can write

$$\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x=e^{-x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}$$

Now apply L'Hospital's Rule to $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}$

Comment: I understand the 1st line,  but I don't understand the 2nd. Where did the 1/x on the bottom come from? What happened to the e?

Comment: Disregard the last question I get it now. Thank you.

Comment: I've deleted the comment.  Perhaps you can do so also.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$
\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x
=\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^x
=\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)^{u-1}
=\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)^{u}\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)^{-1}
$$
and $x\to \infty$ iff $u\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
For such $1^\infty$ problems, you can use the trick below:

> $y=e^{\ln y}$

Then you can apply L'Hospital rule to the exponent part.

Answer (score 1):

As $x$ approaches infinity:
$$\biggl(\frac{x}{x+1}\biggl)^x=\biggl(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\biggl)^x=e^{\biggl(-\frac{1}{x+1}\biggl)x}=e^{-1}$$ by using Euler's method.